# GitHub actions workflow error: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none password], no supported methods remain

Tags: ssh, github-actions

title is pretty much self explainatory, ssh connection is failing. I have the physical server right next to me, its under a vpn which is connected previous to the ssh.

It seems like the server is refusing the user/password pair, but it works just fine on a terminal on my computer.

The sshd_config file has  **PasswordAuthentication yes** and i restarted the ssh service with **service ssh restart**.

Here is the workflow:

```
name: Deployment
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Set up WireGuard
        uses: egor-tensin/setup-wireguard@v1
        with:
          endpoint: ${{ secrets.WIREGUARD_ENDPOINT }}
          endpoint_public_key: ${{ secrets.WIREGUARD_ENDPOINT_PUBLIC_KEY }}
          ips: ${{ secrets.SERVER_IP }}
          allowed_ips: ${{ secrets.WIREGUARD_ALLOWED_IPS }}
          private_key: ${{ secrets.WIREGUARD_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      - name: Deploy to server
        # don't run locally
        if: ${{ !env.ACT }}
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SERVER_IP }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SERVER_USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          port: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_PORT }}
          script: |
            cd ${{ secrets.PROJECT_PATH }}
            git pull ${{secrets.REPO_URL}}
            docker-compose down 
            docker-compose up --build -d
```

Comment: `ssh` is different to `sshd`. Make sure you have set `PasswordAuthentication` to `yes` in the **SSHD** file, and restarted the `sshd` service.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, just restarted the service using **service sshd restart**, same thing happens

Comment: Noticed something quite intereseting, when trying to restart it without sudo, i get an authentication error, i'll add the image above

Comment: ssh connections from outside the network while connected to the vpn are working just fine

Comment: @alvaroLopez, wireguard step is getting stuck at below. Were you able to proceed with wireguard step ?

`
Unpacking wireguard-tools (1.0.20210914-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up wireguard-tools (1.0.20210914-1ubuntu2) ...
wg-quick.target is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
NEEDRESTART-VER: 3.5
NEEDRESTART-KCUR: 6.2.0-1016-azure
NEEDRESTART-KEXP: 6.2.0-1016-azure
NEEDRESTART-KSTA: 1
`

Answer (score 12):

I faced the same issue and fix it by using my local pc ssh private key instead of remote server ssh private key.

If you are using Github action, you have local PC for development, you access Github via ssh and you have a remote server where you want to deploy your code, following steps might apply to you.

- Generate local ssh keys in your local computer
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`
- Copy the content of your private key `~/.ssh/id_rsa` to your clipboard
- Create Github repository secret `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` and paste your private key
- copy the content of your public key `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to your clipboard
- From your local computer ssh your remote host.
- `nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and paste your public key to the next line. If the file does not exit you can create it.
- At that point you should be able to ssh your remote host without providing any password. And so should your Github action which has to behave like your local computer when `appleboy/ssh-action` uses your local private key.

Hope this helps someone in case you need more detail please don't hesitate to read the `appleboy/ssh-action` official doc [here](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action#if-you-are-using-openssh).

Comment: I spend around 2 hours using the SSH private key for the server :(
and your comment saved me :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i had setup previously on VPS and it was working fine, but moving to shared hosting doesn't work unless someone adds public keys to list of authorized_keys

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your `id_rsa.pub` from server in `authorized_keys` file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about wire guard part, but appleboy/ssh-action@master needs key and passphrase

```
      - name: Deploy PROD environment images
    uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
    if: env.CURRENT_BRANCH == 'master'
    with:
      host:       ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST_PROD }}
      port:       ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}
      username:   ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}
      key:        ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      passphrase: ${{ secrets.SSH_PASSPHRASE }}
      script: |
        cd ${{ secrets.PROJECT_PATH }}
        git pull ${{secrets.REPO_URL}}
        docker-compose down 
        docker-compose up --build -d
```

and you can hide these commands into a script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
git pull {LINK_TO_YOUR_REPO} && docker-compose down && docker-compose up --build -d
```

so that you will have:

```
  - name: Deploy PROD environment images
uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
if: env.CURRENT_BRANCH == 'master'
with:
  host:       ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST_PROD }}
  port:       ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}
  username:   ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}
  key:        ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
  passphrase: ${{ secrets.SSH_PASSPHRASE }}
  script: |
    cd ${{ secrets.PROJECT_PATH }}
    ./your_script
```

Comment: Adding the Passphrase still doesn't get to connect to the server, very weird

Comment: did you add your ssh PRIVATE key or PUBLIC key? 
And you can connect with the same ssh private key tho this sever?

Did you add your ssh public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to actually configure the following:

```
Host <ANYNAME>
HostName <IP>
User root
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<PRIVATE_KEY>
IdentitiesOnly=yes
PreferredAuthentications publickey
PasswordAuthentication no
```

[image: ssh/config file]

For those using this guide: https://medium.com/@orestovyevhen/set-up-infrastructure-in-hetzner-cloud-using-terraform-ce85491e92d

```
sed -ie '/^PermitRootLogin/s/^.*$/PermitRootLogin no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

This line of code in the `user_data.yml` prevents root logins.

[image: deny root access]

Answer (score 0):

Solution

- Copy your public SSH key
  cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
- Add it into authorised keys
  nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
- Update permission of the file
  chmod 700 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: Do I run these commands on the server? Or on my local machine?